# Alfresco issue, residual=true and "property type" is empty while "value type" is filled in

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, alfresco, qnames, content-model

I have an issue while creating a content model , in the Node Browser it says "true" under residual and under Property Type it is empty field and under Value Type it says "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/cms/1.0/cs01}id" which is weird cause it's different from all other values. 
[image]

After verifying the model i found that i did a mistake in my QName in java code,so i correct it and the problem goes,
but whenever i restart Alfresco this issue appears again

How to avoid this problem?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete all those contents in which you have used that property with wrong QName.
Also make sure in none of the custom model you have done same mistake.
One more point is make sure if you are using any code to create content that code is using same QName and adding property exactly same as Model because this issue occur when you add property though code and that property is not part of any model Alfresco will allow you to add property but you will face many issue afterwards during content manipulation.

Comment: Note that when the properties are not defined in the content model they are not indexed into Solr, at least in Alfresco 5.1.e

Answer (score 0):

It is not always wrong to use a property that is not defined in the content model.
Sometimes they can be very helpful if you need a more dynamic set of properties.